# Text mining using Watson Knowledge Studio and Watson Discovery

Tags: watson-discovery, watson-knowledge-studio

Could you please tell me how to extract values with specified unit using Watson Knowledge Studio and Watson Discovery.
The idea is based on one using Matplot described in the report ["Empirical assessment of published effect sizes and power in the recent cognitive neuroscience and psychology literature"](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.2000797).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User can create two type models with WKS - Machine Learning model and Rule Base model, and both of then can be deployable to Watson Discovery.
If you like to extract values with specified unit from documents, I think you can use Rule Base model.
For example, if your documents contains a expression of value and unit like "There are more than 10 percents of people being affected by ....", you can define a rule like "number that is followed by phrase 'percents'" to extract the value.